# Deletion of JTable row with custom cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable in which I have added a JButton(Delete button) and a JComboBox as custom cell Editors on two columns. Now, when I select an item in Combobox and click on Delete button, the selected row gets deleted but the combobox of the deleted row is rendered on the row. Do I have to remove the cell editor as well from the table. The code works fine if I dont select my combobox. Please help me.

This is how my code looks like:-

```
class JTableRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor{

    private JComboBox   sens_type_cb;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, Object value, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus, final int row, int column) {     


     if(column == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Row " + row);

            sens_type_cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Radar", "EO", "Aerial", "UAV", "Other"});
            return sens_type_cb;

        }

    }

     @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener)
    {

        sens_type_cb.addActionListener(listener);

    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(final JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, final int row, int column) {


        if(column == 1)
        {
           ActionListener listen = new ActionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {

                        if (table.isEditing())
                            table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                        //table.clearSelection();

                }
            };
            sens_type_cb.addActionListener(listen);
            return sens_type_cb;

        }


        else
            return super.getParent(); 

    }

public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener)
    {

        sens_type_cb.addActionListener(listener);

    }


Next I create Class SensorConf in which I create a table:-

public class SensorConf extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static SensorConf conf_obj = new SensorConf();
    /* A private Constructor prevents any other class from instantiating. */
    //private SensorConf(){ }
    /* Static 'instance' method */
    public static SensorConf getInstance( ) {
        return conf_obj;
    }

    Action delete = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );
        ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
    }
};
    public void CreateTable()
    {


       //  jTable1.setModel(model);
         jTable1.getColumn("S.No.").setPreferredWidth(40);
         jTable1.getColumn("Sensor Type").setPreferredWidth(80);

         jTable1.getColumn("").setPreferredWidth(40);
         jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
         jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
         jTable1.setRowHeight(25);



         javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
         model.addRow(new Object[]{"", "", "", "", "", ""});

         JTableRenderer tableRenderer = new JTableRenderer();


         model.getRowCount();
         model.setValueAt(new Integer(model.getRowCount()), model.getRowCount()-1,0);


         jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(tableRenderer);
         jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(tableRenderer);


         ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(jTable1, delete, 6);

       }

        private SensorConf() {
        initComponents();
        CreateTable();

    }
```

I instantiate an object of my class in main and on clicking an Add Button outside the table, I add a row  model.addRow(new Object[]{"", "", "", "", "", ""}); to my table. Please help me as to find out where am I committing a mistake. 
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "the combobox of the deleted row is rendered on the row." ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If my table has three rows and I select  my ComboBox of second row which  has items like- "1", "2", "3" and I select item "2" and then delete this row, then the second row shall display the combobox with "2" as current item. Its not that the wrong row is getting deleted. i have checked that. I am attaching the code for your reference. Thanks....

Comment: Here is the code..... I have extended CellRenderer and CellEditor and removed a row on click of a button...

Comment: @Shivani Kapur  Here is the code..... did you joking, not good one, know better jokes, well other can do that too, again for better help sooner post an SSCCE,

Comment: class JTableRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor{
    
    private JButton     btn;
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, Object value, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus, final int row, int column) {     
        if(column == 2)
        {          
            btn = new JButton();      
            return btn;
        }

Comment: did you read attached link about an SSCCE, btw @camickr solved your issue +1,

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the comboBox cell is still in editing mode. You would need to make sure editing on the cell has been cancelled before you delete the row.

You can try using [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). I must admit I've never tried this class in your scenario, but the code does invoke `fireEditingStopped()`, so expect it should work.

Edit:

You may find [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to check that. Also, when I am adding a new row, the new row displays the combobox with the selected index as that of the previously deleted combo box, I mean if the deleted row was set at index 2, the newly added row would also be set at index 2 instead of 0 by default. Is this problem also because the cell is still in editing mode.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried Table Button as well as Stop Editing example. Nothing works. The problem is that whenever the combobox is edited and then either a row is deleted or added, the table is not rendering the cell components correctly. It is rendering the deleted components. I don't understand why its happening.

Comment: @ShivaniKapur, the "delete" code works fine for me. The "addRow" method does reset to the last edited value when you create the row with a default value that does not exist in the combo box. This is the default functionality and I don't know how to fix it.